# XamlParseException converting string to routed event handler

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-events, xamlparseexception

I keep getting the error:
ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'.

When I try to run an app. The component causing the error is the filter control component I [downloaded here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170095/WPF-Custom-Control-FilterControl-for-ListBox-ListV). I have successfully used this component for the same type of application before so I don't think it is the component code.

The only difference between the 2 apps I can tell is the wpf page that loads the component sits in a different assembly than the wpf window that loads the page.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Here's the XAML:

```
<FCC:FilterControl x:Name="EquipNumFilterBox" Height="25" Header="Filter..." Margin="10,2,0,0" Filter="FilterBox_Filter" ClearFilter="FilterBox_ClearFilter"/>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
    private void FilterBox_Filter(object sender, FilterControlComponent.FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsFilterApplied = true;
        ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["theDataView"]).View.Refresh();
    }

    private void FilterBox_ClearFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["theDataView"]).View.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: You're somehow giving it a string where a routedeventhandler is expected. In some of the code or markup you haven't posted.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question on SO.

Comment: I added the XAML and code behind. Nothing special about them. There error pops up when the InitializeComponent(); runs.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get around this by assigning the event in the code behind.